# Typescript Inferring parameter types from function records

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a object `fn` with name:function pairs that can take arbitrary parameters. I want to be able to map these functions in order to wrap them with another default function to handle errors in a single location. I have the following code which doesn't even compile giving `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.` on `fn[f](...args)`

```
const fn = {
    ...userActions,
    ...companyActions,
    ...dataActions
};

type A<T extends Array<any>, U> = Record<keyof typeof fn, (...args: T) => Promise<U>>;

function map<T extends Array<any>, U>(f: keyof A<T, U>, ...args: T) {
    fn[f](...args);
}
```

I can wrap functions using the code below but it requires importing the relevant function into the caller file and passing it into `fn` parameter

```
async function run<T extends Array<any>, U>(fn: (...args: T) => Promise<U>, ...temp: Parameters<typeof fn>) {
    await fn(...temp); // works but needs to pass the function itself.
}
```

Is there a way to get around the issue on first piece of code? Basically I want to infer the parameter type by using just the key from a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, in your `map` function, Typescript does not infer that `keyof typeof fn` is *one particular* key of `fn`, but rather that it is the union of all possible keys of fn.  It won't resolve the particular key until you actually pass it a concrete type when you call map.  This in turn means that `args` is being resolve as the intersection of all possible args of all functions in `fn`--not a spread of one particular `args`.

This is a typescript limitation as TS won't resolve the generic inside a function until it is actually passed a concrete type.

So, unfortunately, I do think some assertion is necessary inside the `map` function, but that doesn't prevent you from having good type safety on the inputs and outputs of your `map` function.

That said, I wasn't 100% clear on how you were hoping to use your `map` function, but hopefully this helps understand a way to type this kind of problem:

```js
const userActions = {
  func1: (x:string)=>parseInt(x)
}
const companyActions = {
  func2: (x:number)=>x.toString()
}
const fn = {
    ...userActions,
    ...companyActions,
};

 function map<T extends keyof typeof fn>(f: T, ...args: Parameters<typeof fn[T]>):ReturnType<typeof fn[T]> {
    return (fn[f] as any)(args) as ReturnType<typeof fn[T]>;
}

map("func1", "foo")
map("func2", 3)

//these will error
map("func1", 3)
map("func2", "string")
```

With a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwILCgS3BGBeGAbwCgYYAzOMYARgC4YAKADzumUzAHMBKPAPgAOAQ2RIAkmCgsexAL7FQkWKAC2IsAE90WHPiKkKVYACYGLOmDiqARij79mAOiggAylA7dGshUugUYPokZGRO4QgoOtiQADSGYeFqGtoYMRDxcgDcxKSU1LpBqsKCADwAKjCIzFCIYAAmuADWiJog5DBQmoKI7YH8jOQM5bEw4U6iXBAMAAqiwqqItWKlXT195GAA2uUAuvw8dABKS3DIYOXdiKtXG9t7-AahMMin50ybW%20S7MMK4wloeIxJhAeL9cCcoGcLlcbusOp8HjkFMRioJGAAifK0DGjLEgEAY2RozHYky4mAAZlkxAA9LSoAALRBIGAQRkgOAAG3qVWQyBAyFRJVJxhoFOpwvRWOM5Lx7E4XCJQA).  This will ensure the inputs and output of `map` are typed based on `fn`.

I removed the Promise as I don't think that's fundamental to your question.  It's trivial to add that back in.  Please post more info if this isn't sufficient.

Comment: Works exactly as i intended. Removed `: ReturnType<typeof fn[T]>` which also allowed me to return types that don't belong to the functions while maintaining type inference.

Answer (score -2):

I think your mistake is, you didn't specify the type of the `fn` object, so the typescript couldn't understand whatever you want from him.

As a test I have specified the type the following way:

```js
const fn: { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => any } = {
    ...userActions,
    ...companyActions,
    ...dataActions
};
```

This way you letting the typescript to know that any of the `fn` properties can take a certain amount of parameters.

And now it compiles and works when I call the `map` function!

Comment: Answering a typescript question by recommending the `any` type is not a good idea unless there's a very good reason. It basically disables all type checking. While this is great for silencing errors, there is still an error, you can just no longer see it.

Comment: @AlexWayne Agreed, and the author of the question should definitely make the types more specific when/if he uses this snippet. I don't have information on which exactly types these functions may be, so I used any

Comment: @SlavaSimonov Typescript can infer the types of functions in `fn`. I can see the combined types when i do `Record<keyof typeof fn, (...args: T) => Promise<U>`. My functions look like this `export async function findUser(user: Required<IUserWithoutSession>): Promise<IUser>`. They can have different parameters with any length. `fn` is a key value pair of objects wih function name as key and function itself as value